# A C++ issue: Error C2143, Error C2059, Error C2238

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and this is my first question on Stack Overflow!

Here is the code that is causing my issue:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
    T mAptr*;  // <----  This appears to be the problematic line!
    int mCapacity;  
    int mSize;  
    int mAss;   
... // The rest of the class code is lengthy and doesn't appear to be relevant.
      }
    }
};
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  

error C2059: syntax error : ';'

error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

The compiler is directing me to the line with the pointer when I click on the errors in Visual Studio.

Thanks for reading this, I hope I formatted this correctly!

Comment: That's trivial: `T mAptr*` => `T *mAptr` will be better! Good question format, though (and they say we're tough on newcomers :))

Comment: Where did you read that `T mAptr*` would be a valid declaration? Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: Ahhh thank you Jean! I can't believe I screwed up something so simple. Lightness, I am using a Pearson textbook. I should have referenced it to make sure my syntax was correct before posting here and making myself look foolish!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `T mAptr*;` but it should be `T* mAptr;`